# How can I change email address on Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

It tells me to verify my old email and does not let me verify my new one. What do I do?

Comment: Do you not auto-login by first logging into https://stackexchange.com/ ? That seems to work for me (at present).

Comment: This is not a duplicate, we have a different problem.

Comment: I found that there was a small edit button on your account info page on area15

Comment: It’s right next to he top of the “about me” box.